# OpenCV Panorama: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, spyder

I'm trying to make a panorama from a image set. I'm using Spyder, OpenCV 3.4 and Python 3.7. Here's the code:

1. The main:

   ```
   from stitches import Stitcher
   #from PIL import Image
   import os
   import glob
   import numpy as np
   import imutils
   import cv2

   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/VID_20181208_111037881.mp4')

   img_dir = "C:/Users/user/images"
   data_path = os.path.join(img_dir, '*g')
   files = glob.glob(data_path)
   args = []

   for f1 in files:
       img = cv2.imread(f1)
       args.append(img)

   def retImg(img):
       return img

   for i in args:

       j = i+1

       frame = retImg(i)
       frame2 = retImg(j)

       #imageA = cv2.imread(frame)
       #imageB = cv2.imread(frame2)
       imageA = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
       imageB = imutils.resize(frame2, width=400)

       # stitch the images together to create a panorama
       stitcher = Stitcher()
       (result, vis) = stitcher.stitch([imageA, imageB], showMatches=False)

       frame = result

       # show the images
   cv2.imshow("Keypoint Matches", vis)
   cv2.imshow("Result", result)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   ```
2. The stitch inside stitches.py:

   ```
   def stitch(self, images, ratio=0.75, reprojThresh=4.0, showMatches=False):
   # unpack the images, then detect keypoints and extract
   # local invariant descriptors from them
   (imageB, imageA) = images
   (kpsA, featuresA) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageA)
   (kpsB, featuresB) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageB)

   # match features between the two images
   M = self.matchKeypoints(kpsA, kpsB, featuresA, featuresB, ratio, reprojThresh)

   # if the match is None, then there aren't enough matched
   # keypoints to create a panorama
   if M is None:
       return None

   # together
   (matches, H, status) = M
   result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageA, H, (imageA.shape[1] + imageB.shape[1], imageA.shape[0]))
   result[0:imageB.shape[0], 0:imageB.shape[1]] = imageB

   # check to see if the keypoint matches should be visualized
   if showMatches:
       vis = self.drawMatches(imageA, imageB, kpsA, kpsB, matches, status)

       # return a tuple of the stitched image and the
       # visualization
       return (result, vis)

   # return the stitched image
   return result
   ```

When I compile it, the following error is shown:

```
      File "C:/Users/user/panorama.py", line 44, in <module>
        (result, vis) = stitcher.stitch([imageA, imageB], showMatches=False)

    TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

And I cannot understand why. I'm new to Python, so maybe this mistake is really simple, but I don't know what to do here. Thanks by advance!

Comment: Before passing the images to `stitcher.stitch`, can you `print imageA.shape, imageB.shape` ?

Comment: yes. Result is `(225, 400, 3) (225, 400, 3)`

Comment: Then maybe `stitcher.stitch` has returned `None` instead of a tuple with two values. Please check the return value of `stitcher.stitch` using `ret = stitcher.stitch` instead of `(result, vis) = stitcher.stitch` and then use `print ret`

Comment: wow, it's exactly that. Now what do I do?

Comment: well, guess that I'll need to change how the other functions linked to `stitch` are working. Just found that `matchKeypoints` are returning `None`. okay.